# Зацикливание отрисовки фигуры Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Так вот, осваиваю Swing, пытаюсь отрисовать анимированную фигуру на jpanel. Фигура рисуется, но не перерисовывается, т.е. вместо перемещения координат круга, каждый раз рисуется новый круг с измененными координатами, а старый так и остается на панели. Вот код:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        super("MOON>MOONS");
        initComponents();
        timer.start();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        initBalls();
    }

    private void initBalls() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            Ball ball = new Ball(random.nextInt(200), 200);
            Ball.balls.add(ball);
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (Ball ball : Ball.balls) {
            g.drawOval(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), 60, 60);
        }
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (Ball ball : Ball.balls) {
                ball.move(ball);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

}

public class Ball  {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    public static List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

    public Ball(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addBall(Ball b) {
        balls.add(b);
    }

    public void removeBall(Ball b) {
        balls.remove(b);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public  void move(Ball ball) {
        ball.setX(x+1);
        ball.setY(y+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно очищать экран, чтобы стирать старую фигуру.

Используйте:

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло.